# Issue with window.height and width in localhost and server

Tags: jquery, height, width

I have used the following function to see the height and width of my webiste.

```
function showViewPortSize(display) {
if(display) {
  var height = jQuery(window).height();
  var width = jQuery(window).width();
  jQuery('body').prepend('<div id="viewportsize" style="z-index:9999;position:fixed;top:40px;left:5px;color:#000;background:#fff;padding:10px">Height: '+height+'<br>Width: '+width+'</div>');
  jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    height = jQuery(window).height();
    width = jQuery(window).width();
    jQuery('#viewportsize').html('Height: '+height+'<br>Width: '+width);
  });
}  }

showViewPortSize(true);
```

But the value differs in localhost and server.Why this difference?

Comment: What is difference width or height or both? can you give just example?

Comment: In localhost width:1600,height:894.In server width:1400,height:805

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/60zgf8sp/

Comment: The same you executed.I cant understand.

Comment: What is `height` and `width` on above given url example?

Comment: Height: 551
Width: 597

Comment: As per window size it may varies like My window Height: 663 Width: 804

Comment: thats ok.But the same height and width should be shown in both localhost and server as i am running both in my window?

Comment: Since the height and width of a window is a purely client side and Javascript issue there shouldn't be any direct reason for the server to matter. A better question would be: Why does it matter? And: Do you consider one of the measurements wrong?